# NHibernate Linq Provider question

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Can anyone answer me what are the differences of

Session.Query
  Session.Linq and
  Session.QueryOver

What I'm really interested in:
What would be supported in the future versions.
What should I start to use in a clean project.

Please tell me your thoughts about these three...

Thanks,
Zoltán

Answer (score 5):

Session.Query is the class to use when you want to use the new and much improved linq provider in NHibernate 3.0.  If you are using linq and you are starting a new project, this is the class to use.

Session.Linq is the class to use if you what to use the old linq provider.  I would say that you would only be using this class with older code bases.  The older linq provider is really a wrapper around the Criteria API and, while fine for simpler queries, it is known to have limits once things get more demanding.

Session.QueryOver is a wrapper around the Criteria API of NHibernate.  If you are already well versed in the Criteria API, this is a very approachable interface.  It eliminates most of the strings, replacing them with lambda expressions.  It is a very fluent interface.  The syntax is linq-like but this is *not* a linq provider.

At this point in time I would say you would want to be using the Query and the QueryOver interfaces.